# Best frequency for ATmega328P using internal oscillator?

Tags: avr, oscillator, atmega328p

I wonder what frequency I should set for the internal oscillator of my ATmega328P.

I'll only be reading and outing digital signals, 1s and 0s. I'd like for the processing to be as fast as it can get, but without any disadvantages, like problems when loading the program.

What frequency should I set?

I'll be programming with USBasp.

Comment: Safe range depends on the supply voltage and also if you need any UART comms at certain frequency, and if you have any current limitations. Maybe there is no best at all?

Comment: The internal oscillator runs at 8 MHz.  You can divide this by 8 with one of the fuses.  What do you consider a disadvantage?  You want fast processing, do you have any reason not to use the clock at 8 MHz?

Comment: To be clear, if you are set on using an internal oscillator, you have 3 choices:  128 kHz, 1 MHz, or 8 MHz.  Note that the 128 kHz is a different oscillator and is less accurate.

Comment: no current limitations, and I won't use UART comms, except when loading the program I guess, you think it will be ok to use it at 8 MHz?

Comment: oh, and the supply voltage is 5 V, so what do you guys think?
thanks for the comments

Comment: 8 MHz will be just fine.  Personally done 100s of designs with these using 8 MHz at 5 V, never had a problem.

Comment: thanks a lot! I was curious since I won't be using the official programmer but a generic one

Comment: You need to run the programmer at a lower clock speed to load the program.  That is only during programming.